# Formik FieldArray and useField field validation

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

i am trying to create a custom fieldarray component using FieldArray and useField hook.

The component will be used in a nested form.

Everything was fine except i having issues with the validation. I am unable to validate each field since meta.touched only show a single true or false. (Compare to Formik render errors which able to show which object has been touched).

Example Code:

```
const TestInput = (props: any) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props.name)

  return (
    <FieldArray
      name={props.name}
      render={() => (
        <>
          {field.value.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <TextField
                  {...field}
                  name={`$name}.${index}.key`}
                  value={item.key}
                  helperText={meta.error && meta.error[index] && meta.touched
                    ? meta.error[index].key
                    : ''
                  }
                  error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error[index])} 
                />

                <TextField
                  {...field}
                  name={`$name}.${index}.value`}
                  value={item.key}
                  helperText={meta.error && meta.error[index] && meta.touched
                    ? meta.error[index].value
                    : ''
                  }
                  error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error[index])} 
                />
              </>
             )
           }
        </>
      )
    />
  )
}
```

Is there any alternative to this problem?